# Method to Generate Random Mutually Orthogonal Unitary Matrices

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-analysis, unitary-representations

The title says it all, I'd like to know if such a method exists to generate random mutually orthogonal unitary matrices. If so, any supplementary references would be very much obliged. Thanks again!

Comment: What are mutually orthogonal unitary matrices?

Comment: Presumably $\text{tr}(U^* V) = 0$?

Comment: Yep, $\text{tr}(U^*V) = 0$ is the intended definition of orthogonality between unitary matrices $U$ and $V$. The mutual part just means that all the unitaries are orthogonal to each other.

Comment: how much randomness do you need? if you can constract one set of mutually orthogonal unitaries $U^{(k)}$, $k=1,2,\ldots$, then a random set follows upon multiplication $U^{(k)}\mapsto AU^{(k)}B$ with two random unitaries $A$ and $B$.

Comment: As an aside to Carlo's comment, two mutually orthogonal unitaries can be easily constructed: take diagonal unitaries $U^{(j)} \in U(n)$ for $j = 1,2$ with $U^{(j)}_{kk} = \exp(i\theta^{(j)}_k)$. Orthogonality then means that $\sum_{k=1}^n \exp(i[\theta^{(2)}_k-\theta^{(1)}_k]) = 0$. This can be enforced by choosing $\theta^{(2)}_k-\theta^{(1)}_k = 2\pi k/n$.

Comment: What exactly is the probability measure you want to simulate ?

Comment: There are various parametrisations of $U(n)$ to sample; maybe http://arxiv.org/abs/math-ph/0210057 could help?